# react native - GCM : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and I'm having issues receiving push notifications when the app is killed or not started yet.

When my app is closed and I receive a notification, I'm getting this error in my android logcat:

> W GCM : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000
>   pkg=com.mycustomapp (has extras) }

and according to my research, it means that on receiving notification, it tried to launch the app, but couldn't,  and hence displayed result=CANCELLED message.

P.S. by chance, if this is causing any conflict, I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) in my app.

`react-native@0.53.3`

Comment: Surely, you mean FCM instead of GCM in your title?

Comment: I had written the error received in the console. And yes, it's firebase.